# GCM messages receive order

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I send a sequence of messages (1, 2, 3, 4, 5).

Will my app receive this sequence in order (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)?

I want use GCM to update my app.

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution for this issue?

Comment: you can use [Collapsible messages](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/concept-options#collapsible_and_non-collapsible_messages). It will send to your device only the latest (most recent) notification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the delivery order is not guaranteed, and delivery itself is not guaranteed either. It depends on the the device being connected to GCM server before the time to live of the messages elapses. It also depends on whether or not you are using a collapse key and on the number of messages sent to GCM server for the same registration ID which are not delivered yet.

`Note that the order of delivery is not guaranteed.` ([Source](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/adv.html)).

Comment: @VladimirKulyk That's what happens to old links. That's why we don't accept link only questions. The link in this answer is not an essential part of the answer, it just gives the source from which the quote was taken. That said, it would make sense to search the new GCM documentation to find out if this answer is still valid. Unfortunately, I don't have time for that at the moment.